# Is the "object sender" in EventHandler<T> enough or Should I include a reference of the sender in my custom EventArgs?

Tags: c#, events

Question says it all.

Related thought/question:

Is there a way to "[bubble-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217233/bubbling-up-events/217366#217366)" events then change the original sender without "intercepting" the event?

Example implementation:

```
public class Wheel
{
     public EventHandler<WheelTurningEventArgs> Turning;
}
```

This is the one without the sender in the EventArgs:

```
public class WheelTurningEventArgs : EventArgs
{
      public int TotalTurnCount { get; set; }
}
```

... and this is the one with the sender in the EventArgs.

```
public class WheelTurningEventArgs : EventArgs
{
       public Wheel Wheel {get; set;} //include a reference to the wheel that invoked this event
       public int TotalTurnCount { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Why does your `EventArgs` class have public setters? Wouldn't it make more sense to make it immutable?

Comment: Also, if you implement “bubbling up” as [in the answer you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217233/bubbling-up-events/217366#217366), it *will* preserve the original sender.

Comment: @svick Sorry, I meant the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a routed event, the WheelTurningEventArgs should inherit from the  [RoutedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.aspx) class which will have the original source as well as the sender.